# Different Environment Configuration when building an Angular Application

Tags: angular, environment-variables

I am working with Angular 9 and I have a `config.json` file which is loaded during run-time. I have `dev/config.json` and `prod/config.json` which are loaded depending on if I am running the app locally or building it for production. Up till now I have been manually commenting file paths like this:

```
  // this.configPath = '/config/config-dev.json';
     this.configPath = '/config/config-prod.json';
```

It would be more convenient if the path would always be the same:

```
     this.configPath = '/config/config.json';
```

and the corresponding config.json would be copied depending if I am running locally or building for prod: e.g. in angular.json.

```
"architect": {
        "build": {        
          "options": {                
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/favicon-16x16.png",
              "src/favicon-32x32.png",
              "src/assets",
              "src/config/dev/config.json",
           or "src/config/prod/config.json",
```

Is it possible to setup `angular.json` to detect which config file should be used and to copy it to the config folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Angular version later than 4. They have put a built-in function where you can handle `file replacements`. This is a [good read](https://angular.io/guide/build) for you

For your example, let say you do have a file structure like this

```
└──myProject/src/config/
               └──config.ts
               └──config.prod.ts
               └──config.stage.ts
```

You just need to set what file should the angular replace to the `config.ts` depending on what environment are you going to build with.

Something like this

```
"configurations": {
   "production": {
     "fileReplacements": [
       {
         "replace": "src/environments/config.ts",
         "with": "src/environments/config.prod.ts"
       }
     ],
     ...
```

To build using the production configuration, run the following command:

```
 ng build --configuration=production
```

> Note: The properties that you are going to put to `config.ts` should
>   be the development environment defaults. So every time that you are
>   going to `serve` your application, those are the values going to be pulled